# Moving a plugin js to footer

Tags: plugins

So, a js from a plugin is located in the header based on the setting below:

```
wp_register_script('plugin_min', plugin_url . 'scripts/scripts.min.js' );
```

Now, I can change it so that it will be located in the footer by editing the plugin file:

```
wp_register_script('plugin_min', plugin_url . 'scripts/scripts.min.js', array(), false, true );
```

Of course editing the plugin file is not a good idea since it will be overwritten upon update.

So, to do it properly, should I deregister it first then re-register in the function.php?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your thought is correct.

By editing the plugin file you lose updatability. So unregistering and reregistering it in the functions.php would be the correct way to do it.